# Website developmet with JBOSS

Tags: java, ant, jboss, web

In my company there are around 30-40 developers and all of them are working on same website developmet project. Project is devided in many modules. My problem is every developer has run his own JBOSS to run his JAVA code. With Ant, they build the Ear file and deploye them on JBOSS which is running on their local desktop. This require huge memory and slow down the desktop.
Isn't possible if we can run the JBOSS on different server machine and all developer use this machine to run and test their code simultaneously? Hope you guys understand my question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. In which OS are the developers working? What JBoss product are you using, because there are different requirements for JBoss EAP, JBoss EPP and JBoss SOA?

Comment: We are working on huge website project and development is on Windows with eclips IDE and we are using JBoss EAP. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a continuous integration server like [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins).  With Jenkins you have different "projects". Each project builds the code and runs an instance of JBoss.

With Jenkins you can have a different project for each developer (if that's what you want) and you can get the added benefits of Jenkins compiling and running unit-tests each time a developer checks in code.

Comment: I dont know if this is the answer. I have gone through the link, but I didn't see any configuration which is made for multiple users. what I was thinkink if the JBoss can create separate session for each user and each user will work in their session without interepting other users. Other users are doing some mannual testing at the same time some user are deploying their build using Ant for code testing.

Comment: Sorry about the link, I had actually misunderstood it.

Comment: I removed the link from the answer.  However, read the documentation on how to setup Jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Use+Jenkins
You'll need this JBoss plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JBoss+Management+Plugin
The idea is you have different "projects" in Jenkins.  Each project builds the code and runs an instance of JBoss.  So if you wanted to, each developer would "own" a Jenkin's project.  We know this can be done, see this case study: http://jboss-qa.blogspot.com/2007/10/taking-continuous-integration-to.html
(Jenkins was previously known as Hudson)

Answer (score 0):

it is possible.you can achieve this by running the JBOSS Application Server on a particular IP.to do this you have to use ./run.sh -b followed by the IP Address of the machine on which you want to run the application server.with this your server is ready.now every client has to connect to the server with the help of that IP address.for this you replace the loopback address(127.0.0.1) with the IP address on which application server is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can but with many developers all together it can get tricky.

It is possible to run a single instance of jboss but then you run into problems with either hot deploys, slowing work and cross contaminating if different devs work on the same code, or no hot deploys, in which case the server has to be shutdown every time an app is deployed/changed. In a testing environment this doesn't work very well.

The other way would be to run a separate instance for every dev to run tests on but this can get very cost intensive in both money and server resources. You also have a nightmare when you try to merge changes from these various environments.

Some good organization might help. We run three layers:development, staging, production. Development is purely for your developers. Bug tracking and testing is handled in staging while production is for user and customer evaluations(assuming the product hasn't been rolled yet). Use a good repository to code up changes from local machines to development, then the admins roll groups of changes to staging. It doesn't really solve your problem of the memory on local machines but I thought I would try and help out with some enterprise level stuff.

One quick fix would be to put tons of RAM on each machine, its dirt cheap anyway. Then set your server memory settings up way higher. That will reduce your cpu loads a bit and reduce the number of time you see the dreaded permgen error from too many hot deploys